# X server running but no GUI showing

Tags: raspbian-jessie, screen, xorg, lxde

I'm using a Raspberry Pi model B (512 MB RAM) with the following touch [screen](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B01CNLYL1C/) and the latest image of Raspbian. The screen drivers are ok, since I can see the loading screen and the tty. If I plug in a keyboard, all is fine (textual, but fine).

The problem is that the GUI isn't loading. I have configured the automatic GUI and login through `raspi-config`, I think all the necessary packages have been installed (following [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=37564) post), but it doesn't work. After the booting information I am stuck with a black screen with a fixed (not blinking) cursor on the top left corner. `service lightdm stop` brings the cursor blinking, `service lightdm start` gets it fixed again.

Seems to me that the X server has started correctly but I'm on the wrong virtual terminal; I have tried using `chvt` on all the terminals from 1 to 12 without success. Log files `.xsession-error`, `LXDE/run.log` or `Xorg.0.log` don't show any error (at least, none I can mark as error), but I can provide them if needed.

I've run out of option, can you help me?

**Edit**: `dmesg|grep fbtft`

```
[   13.116199] fbtft: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   13.159355] fbtft_of_value: regwidth = 16
[   13.159375] fbtft_of_value: buswidth = 8
[   13.159390] fbtft_of_value: debug = 0
[   13.159403] fbtft_of_value: rotate = 270
[   13.159416] fbtft_of_value: fps = 30
[   13.159430] fbtft_of_value: txbuflen = 32768
```

`dmesg|grep /dev/fb` provides no result.

`ls /dev/fb*` shows two devices `fb0` and `fb1`

Comment: Am I right that this screen works completely via SPI, without HDMI connection or similar?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yes, it is connected through the 26-GPIO, no HDMI involved. On the screen's website they provide the drivers and a bunch of scripts to configure the device (like setting the orientation). As i wrote, it works if use just the tty.

Comment: Can you find out (via `dmesg` or similar) which framebuffer device represents this screen? I suppose your Xorg server is trying to start on HDMI screen instead, that's why you don't see anything.

Comment: You can also try `FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fbX startx` with `X` in `fbX` equal to 0, 1, etc. Eventually you'll find the right one.

Comment: `lsmod` says that modules `fb_ili9486` and `fbtft` are loaded.

Comment: [Here][1] is the complete `dmesg` output

[1]: http://pastebin.com/0xq5eAa8

Comment: `fbtft` is the driver. It should create special files inside `/dev/` filesystem, and you need to find out which one it is.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read pastebin. Could your please run `dmesg | grep fbtft`, `dmesg | grep /dev/fb` and `ls /dev/fb*`? Hopefully, there won't be much output. Or just keep trying `startx` on different framebuffers.

Comment: Thanks. I suggest you try `FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx`, since [this page](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/How-it-works) seems to suggest it's the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to the fact that while your driver is loaded and usable, Xorg seems to still pick the HDMI output (which you probably haven't disabled). You should tell Xorg to use the right framebuffer device, which defaults to `fb1` according to this [wiki page](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/How-it-works). You should be able to see this device name in `dmesg` output if you search for "graphics" or "fb_ili9486":

```
dmesg | grep graphics
graphics fb1: fb_ili9486 frame buffer, 320x480, ...
```

To tell Xorg which framebuffer to use, you have two options:

If you start Xorg from command line, use `FRAMEBUFFER` variable:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx # or startlxde, etc.
```

If you want Xorg to start automatically, modify its configuration files (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or files inside `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`):

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "TFT"
  Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Now I have a different problem (swapped X and Y axis), which I'll dig into and, if necessary, I'll post another question.

Comment: @Cynical If those are touchscreen axes, you may want to check [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60872/inverted-gpio-touchscreen-using-99-calibration-conf) question.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61053/tft-lcd-3-5-display-with-inverted-axis), I got to that question too, but the answer I found was slightly different. Thanks anyway!