# TFT LCD 3.5 display with inverted axis

Tags: touchscreen, xorg

Following my [previous](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/x-server-running-but-no-gui-showing) question, I now have a working LCD display, but with a different issue.

The problem is the same as in [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60872/14936) question, yet I am unable to find a solution.

I don't have a `xorg.conf` file, but in `xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` I put the result of `xinput_calibration`, which is:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
    Option  "MinX"  "61348"
    Option  "MaxX"  "3095"
    Option  "MinY"  "3738"
    Option  "MaxY"  "62309"
    Option  "SwapXY"    "1" # unless it was already set to 1
    Option  "InvertX"   "1"  # unless it was already set
    Option  "InvertY"   "1"  # unless it was already set
EndSection
```

`xinput list` gives

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ADS7846 Touchscreen                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput list-props 6` gives

```
Device 'ADS7846 Touchscreen':
    Device Enabled (116):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (117): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix (246):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (247):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (248): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (249):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (250):    0, 0
    Device Node (251):  "/dev/input/event0"
    Device Product ID (252):    0, 0
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (253):   0
```

and, as you can see, none of the options specified in `99-calibration.conf` is used.

If I try running, as suggested in the answers on the other question

```
xinput set-prop 6 "Evdev Axis Calibration" <Min-X> <Max-X> <Min-Y> <Max-Y>
xinput set-prop 6 "Evdev Axes Swap" 1
```

I get

```
property 'Evdev Axis Calibration' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
property 'Evdev Axes Swap' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your issue is the same as mine, the new Jessie kernel / img uses `libinput` as it's mouse drivers instead of the old `evdev`, which either ignores `99-calibration.conf` or uses a different config file altogether (in my experience.  I don't know that for sure).

The solution is to open `40-libinput.conf` and change `Driver "libinput"` to `Driver "evdev"` for the `touchscreen` section.

Then you have to run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev`

[This is where I found the answer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=179477#p1163460)

---

Edit

I just figured out that if you have the resistive and capacitive modules loaded at the same time, the resistive module will override the configuration for the capacitive module and the same screen issues will occur.

So if you intend to use one pi image for different screen types, edit the `/etc/modules` file and make sure `stmpe-ts` is listed **before** `f6xo6-ts`.  Then go to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` folder and rename `95-stmpe.rules` file to `94-stmpe.rules`

There's probably a script you can write to check which screen is on the pi, then dynamically switch the modules.

Answer (score 5):

Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1" worked for me too!
after 2 afternoons of work it finally worked out
Im using the 3.5 TFT GPIO verison - ADS7846 Touchscreen
here is my file

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
        Option  "MinX"  "4551"
        Option  "MaxX"  "62076"
        Option  "MinY"  "62002"
        Option  "MaxY"  "3430"
        Option  "SwapXY"        "1" # unless it was already set to 1
        Option  "InvertX"       "0"  # unless it was already set
        Option  "InvertY"       "0"  # unless it was already set
        Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
```

this was meant to run octoprint per following instructions

https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show
and 
https://github.com/BillyBlaze/OctoPrint-TouchUI/wiki/Setup:-Boot-to-Browser-(OctoPi-or-Jessie-Light)

Answer (score 2):

After searching and testing for a while, I found that you need to set the Transformation Matrix in the `Calibration` section of `xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf`:

```
Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1"
```

fixed the problem. I'm still not sure it's the right way to do that, so if anyone has a better option, I'd gladly listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the Transformation matrix as such:

Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1"

But otherwise, this was the way to make it work for me.

https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/445

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

Literally spent 4 hours trying to fix it and in the end, this was the code:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
    Option  "MinX"  "1934"
    Option  "MaxX"  "61280"
    Option  "MinY"  "62309"
    Option  "MaxY"  "3738"
    Option  "SwapXY"        "1" # unless it was already set to 1
    Option "InvertX"        "0"
    Option "InvertY"        "0"
    Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
```

The only thing i needed to add was as said above:
    Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1"

Answer (score 0):

I had to swap both axis, and invert both of them as well, and then widen the input field (reduce minx, increase max, reduce miny, increase maxy)

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier        "calibration"
MatchProduct      "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
Option "MinX"     "1834"
Option "MaxX"     "62280"
Option "MinY"     "61309"
Option "MaxY"     "3738"
Option "SwapXY"   "1" # unless it was already set to 1
Option "InvertX"  "0"
Option "InvertY"  "0"

Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 -1 1 -1 0 1 0 0 1"

EndSection
```